# Search Predicate Builder

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7, predicatebuilder, sitecore7.2

I am using Lucene search with Sitecore 7.2 and using predicate builder to search for data. I have included a computed field in the index which is a string. When I search on that field using `.Contains(mystring)`,  it fails when there is 'and' present in `mystring`. If there is no 'and' in the `mystring` it works.

Can you please suggest me anything?

Comment: This is only the case with computed index field, for a normal indexed field it works fine

Comment: This is how I am adding the computed indexfield, it is a string value <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField"> <field fieldName="area" storageType="no" indexType="TOKENIZED" >MyClass,MyAssembly</field> </fields>

Comment: Could you please add some code samples here?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thank you for your reply. However I have solved it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, taking a hint from @Stephen Pope 's reply. In order to make your computed field untokenized you have to add it to both raw:AddFieldByFieldName and AddComputedIndexField.

See link below
http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Martina-Welander-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/09/Sitecore-7-Search-Tips-Computed-Fields.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Lucene by default, when the field and query is processed, will strip out what are called "stop words" such as `and` and `the` etc.

If you dont want this behaviour you can add an entry into the `fieldMap` section of your configuration to tell Sitecore how to process the field ...

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
   <field fieldName="YOURFIELDNAME" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
       <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
   </field>
   ...
</fieldNames>
```

.. this example tells Sitecore, for that field, to not tokenize and also to put everything into lowercase. You can change to different analyzers to get the results you want.

You can try setting the indexType to `TOKENIZED` but still using the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer` as another combination. `UN_TOKENIZED` will mean that your string will be processed as a single token which may not be what you want.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thank you for your reply. Is it the same behaviour for computed indexes? I am using something like this   <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">  <field fieldName="area" storageType="no" indexType="TOKENIZED" >MyClass,MyAssembly</field>  </fields>

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately no luck. One thing I would like to mention is this happens when I use predicate builder, following code works perfectly fine: context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>().Where(p => p.area == myString );

Comment: I have solved it, taking a hint from @Stephen Pope 's reply

In order to make your computed field untokenized you have to add it both raw:AddFieldByFieldName and AddComputedIndexField. See link below

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Martina-Welander-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/09/Sitecore-7-Search-Tips-Computed-Fields.aspx

Comment: Apologies, this behaviour is changed in the upcoming v7.5 so you only have to define it in one place (the fieldMap). Sorry for the confusion Aman!

Comment: plus1 for largely answering the question!